# mySQL Restar tabla resultado de JOINS a una tabla original

Tags: mysql

Resulta que tras usar un SELECT * FROM + varios JOINS tal que...

```
SELECT * FROM EMBARCACION RIGHT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM EMBARCACION LEFT JOIN POSICION
  ON EMBARCACION.matricula=POSICION.matricula JOIN VENTA
  ON VENTA.matricula=EMBARCACION.matricula JOIN SOCIO 
  ON SOCIO.IDSocio=VENTA.IDSocio  
  WHERE POSICION.IDposicion is not null AND POSICION.fechaFinal is null
) WHERE POSICION.IDPosicion is null
```

como resultado obtengo una tabla.

A la tabla EMBARCACION original le quiero restar la tabla que he obtenido con el SELECT pero en la misma sentencia y sin tener que crear una tabla física.

Alguna idea de como hacerlo ?

Comment: Tendras que hacer un update select con join sobre la consulta. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query

Comment: Sintiéndolo mucho no entiendo nada del enlace... Por qué debería querer actualizar una tabla ? No se cómo combinar los conocimientos del enlace con los selects que yo quiero hacer...

Comment: Si no quieres actualizar la tabla ¿donde vas a guardar los datos?

Answer (score 0):

Ésta consulta debería hacer lo que pides:

```
DELETE FROM EMBARCACION WHERE embarcacion_matricula in 
SELECT embarcacion_matricula FROM EMBARCACION RIGHT JOIN 
(
     SELECT * FROM EMBARCACION LEFT JOIN POSICION
     ON EMBARCACION.matricula=POSICION.matricula JOIN VENTA
     ON VENTA.matricula=EMBARCACION.matricula JOIN SOCIO 
     ON SOCIO.IDSocio=VENTA.IDSocio  
     WHERE POSICION.IDposicion is not null AND POSICION.fechaFinal is null
)
WHERE POSICION.IDPosicion is null
```

Básicamente es un delete from embarcacion donde la matricula (o el id que corresponda) se encuentre dentro del conjunto de id's (IN) que devuelve la subconsulta

```
SELECT embarcacion_matricula FROM EMBARCACION RIGHT JOIN 
    (
         SELECT * FROM EMBARCACION LEFT JOIN POSICION
         ON EMBARCACION.matricula=POSICION.matricula JOIN VENTA
         ON VENTA.matricula=EMBARCACION.matricula JOIN SOCIO 
         ON SOCIO.IDSocio=VENTA.IDSocio  
         WHERE POSICION.IDposicion is not null AND POSICION.fechaFinal is null
    )
    WHERE POSICION.IDPosicion is null
```

Espero te sea útil!